# Dynamically generated meta Title & Description pages Indexed with Wrong Page Title In Google

Tags: php, .htaccess, title, meta

I have generated Dynamic Web Pages Using URL Rewriting and created meta Title & Description for that.

But it indexed in google with the Wrong title.

Some people Suggested that I reduce the Title Length and resubmit Sitemap in Webmaster and I have resubmitted before 3 Months But still facing the same issue :
Url= `http://pincodehunt.in`

code:

```
<?php
echo"<title> Pin Code Of ".$Post_name."|Zip Code OF ".$Post_name."</title>";

?>
```